# nodejs package.json : install one of the dependencies in a different folder

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

Is there a way to specify a target different from "node_modules" for one of my dependencies?

For example-

```
"dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^2.6.1",
    "mobx-react": "^3.5.8",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "Header-Component":"git+https:/***/***/Header-Component#master"
  }
```

I would like Head-Component to be installed in my "src" folder, and not "node-modules"

Answer (score 0):

you can install in node_modules at first then move it to your directory then require your own directory in your code to use that module so then you can completely remove nod_modules folder after that